# Wordpress .innerHtml image

Tags: javascript, image, wordpress

I created a wordpress theme, that is using javascript .innerHTML to insert content into certain divs. It is inserting text fine, but is not inserting images.

```
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML='<img src="images/header.gif"/>'
```

My knowledge on php is terrible but I also tried this

```
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML='<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/mainimage.jpg" title="" alt="" />';
```

here is index.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?><?php wp_title(); ?></title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress <?php bloginfo('version'); ?>" /> <!-- leave this for stats please -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" title="RSS .92" href="<?php bloginfo('rss_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Atom 0.3" href="<?php bloginfo('atom_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/javascript.js"></script>
<?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly&format=link'); ?>
<?php //comments_popup_script(); // off by default ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
 <body  onload="formatPage();">

  <div id="container">
    <div id="logo"></div>

    <div id="title"></div>

    <div id="nav"></div>

    <div id="content"></div>


    <div id="footer"></div> 
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Here is javascript.js

```
      function formatPage(){
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML='<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/header.gif" title="" alt="" />';
}
```

I understand my doctype is outdated and there may be some unneeded php in the header.

Comment: Try adding the word `echo` before `bloginfo` in the second example.

Comment: No need to add `echo`. Are you sure that `mainimage.jpg` exists in the dir you supposed?

Comment: I tried echo, it did not work.  mainimage.jpg does not exist but in my actual code I am still referring to header.gif.

Comment: Can u add the whole script you are using and the HTML to the question

Comment: Ya no problem, just added it.  I appreciate that you guys are willing to help me out with this

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that the image path is correct. You must include that js file is in head section. That's why the pic is not getting loaded.And also move the head portion to header.php if its now in index.php.

Comment: It did not go through.  I have an images directory inside my themes root.  That is what I am trying to refer to, am I going the wrong way about this?

Comment: the path is correct if images folder is in your theme root folder.Have you checked after writing the script inside the "title" div

Comment: It does happen to work, when inserted directly into the div.  I happened to have a syntax error I did not see right away.  The .innerHTML is still not going through though